# Sandbox bitcoins status is pending

Tags: coinbase.com

I have registered on https://sandbox.coinbase.com before, two days ago. They are showing me that I have received 100,000 bits.

It's been 3 days that status is still in pending state. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easiest and fastest to simply request addition testnet coin from a faucet. I'd suggest [TP's TestNet Faucet](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/) which at the time of this writing is giving out 0.94 tbtc per request.

If this also doesn't work, it's possible that Coinbase's testnet node is down, in which case you'd have to [contact their support team](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/emails/new).

Please remember to return your tbtc to TP's Faucet once your done with it!

Comment: How long does it take to get bitcoins from TP's ?